# Will TikZ compilation become faster?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I find that TikZ compilations are rather slow. I often work with old computers and the LaTeX compilation is very fast but TikZ slows down the process. Externalizing the graphics helps but making a separate compilation for the graphics is not the idea in my opinion. I think that TikZ is still under development and it's a modern language so will his compilation become faster?

Comment: I'm not sure what would count as an "answer" to this question. Other than "No, TikZ compilation is unlikely to get noticeably more efficient. TikZ compilation will speed up as a function of increasing computer power, however."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is not clear what the question is here, except for the title. If you have a specific problem with externalization please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I don't have a problem with externalization.

Comment: Well, the externalization ensures, that the TikZ graphic is only compiled again, whenever it's changed, i think that's a first idea. What else do you think, should be changed? I mean, do you have any specific ideas of optimization, i.e. where you think it would be possible to improve the compilation speed? Without that - i think - there is no real answer to your question.

Comment: Maybe ideas or a working solution for externalization, like using something as `make` or similar. And are there any ways to include the TikZ code into the main document, still it being processed only when it changes (possibly using something as md5 checksums on the TikZ code to detect changes)? These are questions that should be considered in my opinion...

Comment: Well, that should be possible using the `external`-Library of TikZ, haven't used it myself, but saw it when helping a friend, the fastest introduction i could find was this one http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/

Comment: I suppose TikZ could get faster relative to processor speed if the TeX code in which TikZ is implemented were optimized.  But I don't know how possible that is.  Maybe if TikZ were baked into the format?  That would probably only quicken the compilation of the preamble, not the actual diagrams.